# Proper holomorphic maps and the degree of the map

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose f is holomorphic and maps U onto V, both being disks.

If f is proper, does this induce a well defined degree for f?
And does the converse hold?

What are some tools that can help me see if minor perturbation of a proper holomorphic map of degree d is still proper and of degree d or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For proper functions $f: D\to D$ you can define the degree as the cardinality of $f^{-1}(z)$ for $z$ which is not a critical value of $f$. (Here $D$ is the open unit disk.) To see that this is independent of $z$, prove that the restriction $f: D'\to D''$ is a covering map, where $D'\subset D$ is the set  of regular values and $D''=f^{-1}(D')$. To prove the covering property note that the restriction is a proper local homeomorphism. 
To prove that the degree is stable under small perturbations, use [Rouché's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).